# How to display image in popup

Tags: javascript, html

I have got a csv file which contain all attributes, such as name, image url, price of every restaurant in London. I use the code below to display popup when my mouse moves to the point of the restaurant in map. However, it can only show the image url text but not the image itself. Is that possible to make the popup display the image of every restaurant directly by changing the code below?

```
var mypopup = new mapboxgl.Popup({closeButton: false});
map.on('mouseover', 'Restaurant', function (e) {
mypopup
.setLngLat(e.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
.setHTML("<h3>" + e.features[0].properties.name + "</h3>Categories: " + e.features[0].properties.categories + "<br />Image Url: " + e.features[0].properties.image_url + "<br />Location: " + e.features[0].properties.location + "<br />Phone Number: " + e.features[0].properties.display_phone + "<br />Price: " + e.features[0].properties.price + "<br />Rating: " + e.features[0].properties.rating)
.addTo(map);
});
map.on('mouseenter', 'Food', function () {
map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
map.on('mouseleave', 'Food', function () {
map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
mypopup.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the image url in and `img` html element e.g. `<img src="e.features[0].properties.image_url" />`. You may have to do some styling if you want them all the same size, for instance.